# How to execute complex linux commands in Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shell, qprocess

I want to restart the computer by running a command in linux using `QProcess`. I have hard-coded my root password in my application.

When i run the following in a terminal it works perfect:

```
echo myPass | sudo -S shutdown -r now
```

When i put the command in a shell script and call it via `QProcess` it is also successful :

```
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "myScript.sh");
```

But i can not run it by directly passing to `QProcess`:

```
process.startDetached("echo myPass | sudo -S shutdown -r now ");
```

It will just print `myPass | sudo -S shutdown -r now`

How is it possible to run such relatively complex commands directly using `QProcess`. (Not putting in a shell script).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key methods that exist for this purpose established in `QProcess`:

> [void QProcess::setProcessChannelMode(ProcessChannelMode mode)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessChannelMode)

and

> [void QProcess::setStandardOutputProcess(QProcess * destination)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputProcess)

Therefore, the following code snippet would be the equivalence of `command1 | command2` without limiting yourself to one interpreter or another:

```
QProcess process1
QProcess process2;

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

process1.start("echo myPass");
process2.start("sudo -S shutdown -r now");
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);

// Wait for it to start
if(!process1.waitForStarted())
    return 0;

bool retval = false;
QByteArray buffer;
// To be fair: you only need to wait here for a bit with shutdown,
// but I will still leave the rest here for a generic solution
while ((retval = process2.waitForFinished()));
    buffer.append(process2.readAll());

if (!retval) {
    qDebug() << "Process 2 error:" << process2.errorString();
    return 1;
}
```

You could drop the `sudo -S` part because you could run this small program as root, as well as setting up the rights. You could even set setuid or setcap for the shutdown program.

What we usually do when building commercial Linux systems is to have a minimal application that can get setuid or setcap for the activity it is trying to do, and then we call that explicitly with `system(3)` or `QProcess` on Linux. Basically,

I would write that small application to avoid giving full root access to the whole application, so to restrict the access right against malicious use as follows:

```
sudo chmod u+s /path/to/my/application
```

Comment: This works well and i like it because it is more general and more in  a Qt way. I don't know what is this for: process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);

Comment: @Nejat: yeah, it may work without that, but last time I had issues when not having that. The purpose of it is to redirect the child process' output to the main process, so, yeah, that may be unnecessary for your case.

Answer (score 3):

First, you could configure `sudo` to avoid asking you the password. For instance by being member of the `sudo` group and having the line

```
 %sudo  ALL=NOPASSWD:  ALL
```

in your `/etc/sudoers` file. Of course not asking the password lowers the security of your system.

To answer your question about Qt, remember that [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), like all [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shells, hence `/bin/sh`, accept the `-c` argument with a string (actually [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is forking a `/bin/sh -c`). So just execute

```
 process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "-c" 
                       << "echo myPass | sudo -S shutdown -r now");
```

As [AntiClimacus answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322814/841108), puting your root password inside an executable is a bad idea.

Comment: It is a suboptimal idea, because Qt has dedicated API for this which does not limit you to an interpreter.

Comment: Also, it seems the OP already tried this, and also asked `How is it possible to run such relatively complex commands directly using QProcess. (Not putting in a shell script).`

Answer (score 0):

You must put your command in a shell script and execute `sh` or `bash` with QProcess with your shell script as argument, because your command contains `|`, which *must* be interpreted by `sh` or `bash`.

However, it's just my opinion, but: I don't think it is a good solution to do what you are doing, i.e. include your root password in an executable.

Comment: This is not recommended as it restricts the availability to the given interpreter.

Comment: I have already tried that successfully if you read the question.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Do you know a Linux system without /bin/sh ? The question was about Linux, not all operating systems. If the command was more complex, with several pipes / redirectors, what do you do ? 10 QProcess ? It's also more flexible to dedicate the command in a shell script: if you would like to change the command, you don't need to compile again your executable.

Comment: The OP explicitly tried this and asked: `How is it possible to run such relatively complex commands directly using QProcess. (Not putting in a shell script).` -> You are not attempting to answer the question. Besides, you are also confused: interpreter is _not_ sh, but _bash_. And, yes, the whole embedded industry is based on busybox or toybox without bash. Many people also use zsh instead of bash on desktop, et cetera. The OP wanted to avoid it and find a cross-solution. I still think you are just reiterating what the OP wrote, so it is not an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I'm not confused: sh is not bash, and is not always a symlink to bash, sh is an entire and independent shell (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell). And even there is no bash and no sh, e.g. if you use zsh, dash, or other shells, then, in this case, sh points to the right interpreter.

Comment: You seem to be still confused. You are not answering the OP's question. You write what he has already tried and wished to avoid. As far as the shell goes, different shells can have different syntax for dealing with piping, etc. There is no standard for it. This solution will be specific, and not necessarily working in another shell. I am not sure what is unclear about it, or what it has to do with symlinks pointing to bash, busybox's ash, etc. That seems to be red-herring to me.