# Qt. Copy resource file in QProcess

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to copy a file I have attached to my program like resource in a `/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/` (needs `sudo` rights)

If the destination path was in `/home` I could do something like that:

```
QFile file(QStringLiteral(":/resourcefile"));
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    file.copy("/home/user/......./resourcefile");
}
```

But it's not my case. Therefore I must to use QProcess (I think) in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322739/how-to-execute-complex-linux-commands-in-qt):

```
QProcess process1, process2;

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);
process1.start("echo mypass");
process2.start("sudo -S cp <resourcefile> /usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/file.sql");
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
bool retval = false;
QByteArray buffer;
while ((retval = process2.waitForFinished()));
    buffer.append(process2.readAll());
.....
```

And the question is....how could I pass the `<resourcefile>` to process2?

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods:

```
QProcess::setArguments(const QStringList &arguments)
QProcess::setNativeArguments(const QString &arguments)
QProcess::setStandardInputFile(const QString &fileName)
QProcess::setStandardOutputFile(const QString &fileName, QIODevice::OpenMode mode = Truncate)
```

look at this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

Comment: Thank you, but I can't help me. My real problem is that "resourcefile" is not a phisical file that bash can use. I go to edit the question for clarify