# System command executed from QT does not work for service

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

Why does the service not get restarted?

```cpp
void page_maintenance_general::on_rtunnel_restart_Button_clicked()
{
    QProcess process;
    // Seems to work, but in journalctl it's clear it did not execute.
    process.start("echo 'pwdshereshouldbeavoidedIknow' | sudo -S -n systemctl restart rtunnel.service");
    //process.start("nmcli networking connectivity"); // works fine

    process.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString feedback = process.readAllStandardOutput();
    //QString feedback = process.readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << "rtunnel restart status: " << feedback;
    ui->backend_status_label->setText("rtunnel restart " + feedback);

}
```

- For an innocent command, things work well. `nmcli networking connectivity` gives `full`
- `echo 'pwdthatshouldbeavoidedIknow' | sudo -S -n systemctl restart rtunnel.service` works when executed as the same user that executes the program in a terminal.
- Other `sudo` commands work too in the same program e.g.

```cpp
QString command = "echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S shutdown -r 0"; // works fine
system(qPrintable(command));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Pipes in `QProcess.start()`. After some testing I found out that `sudo` doesn't work as expected when not called from a command line interpreter.

Start a `bash` and write your commands to it. Remember to exit the bash! Note that the newline characters in the `write`'s are important!

Note: The -S parameter in sudo is used to read the password from standard input instead of from the terminal.

```cpp
QProcess process;
process.start("bash");
process.waitForStarted();
process.write("echo 'pwdshereshouldbeavoidedIknow' | sudo -S systemctl restart rtunnel.service\n");
process.write("exit\n");
process.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was still unsuccessful. Even after executing László Papp's solution from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322739/how-to-execute-complex-linux-commands-in-qt

Comment: @lode I think my new solution should work for you. On my system I was able to exec commands by sudo. I tested with `sudo -S sleep 3`.

Comment: Yes, the new solution did the trick. thx! I had to remove the -n from the sudo command too. will edit answer as soon as it allows me to.